# subprocess not working in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using Python 2.6 for reasons I cannot avoid.  I have run the following tiny bit of code on the Idle command line and am getting an error I do not understand.  How can I get around this?

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> x = subprocess.call(["dir"])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    x = subprocess.call(["dir"])
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 444, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 821, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>>
```

Comment: Does the `dir` command work when you type it directly on your Windows command prompt? (as it should)

Comment: works for me on both python2,7 and 3.3. it must be system setup issue

Comment: Yep, dir works, and it also works in os.popen

Comment: I tried the latest python as well and got the same error.  If you have any idea what is wrong with my setup, please let me know.

Comment: if it works on the shell and popen then your setup should be fine. strange. i run it on linux tho maybe windows is different

Comment: I have tried it on another machine and got the same message, both machines are windows 7 64 bit

Comment: @FooBarUser See the last paragraph of my answer for an explanation why it works on Linux.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try setting `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.call(["dir"], shell=True)
```

`dir` is a shell command meaning there is no executable that you could call. So `dir` can only be called from a shell, hence the `shell=True`.

Note that [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) will only execute the command without giving you its output. It will only return the exit status of it (usually 0 when it was successful).

If you want to get the output, you can use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['dir'], shell=True)
' Datentr\x84ger in Laufwerk C: ist … and more German output'
```

---

To explain why it works on Unix: There, `dir` is actually an executable, usually placed at `/bin/dir`, and as such accessible from the PATH. In Windows, `dir` is a feature of the command interpreter `cmd.exe` or the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet in PowerShell (aliased to `dir`).